# Need to install a package without updating OR How to remote access RPi over the internet w/o updating RPi or using port forwarding

Tags: software-installation, remote, update

As the question text reads, I need to enable remote access on my RPi over the internet without using port forwarding. I have a custom OS and can not do a general update without overwriting some of the customization.  I think that using weaved is great but it will not find the software using apt-get unless I do a general update first. I might be able to update a specific software if needed but not sure what those are.

Comment: So, you need to remotely setup the device, without being able to connect via the default SSH configuration? Why can't you update the RPi?

Comment: I am working on a customized image and can break it if I update the software. I have found through further research that the apt-get update does not actually update any software but instead the index of the repository so it is fine to use. Now given an updated repository I can get the software I need easily. I am using weaved and so far its great (even if its a little slow). Thank you for your response but I think I got it figured out.

Comment: Would you mind self answering then? It could help people with similar problems in the future :)

Comment: Please note that I rolled your edit to the title back, that's not how things are done here. If you think your answer sufficiently addresses the question feel free to accept it.

Comment: Thank you for doing so. It wont let me accept it yet. Gotta wait a few hours

Answer (score 1):

I found that when using the apt-get update command does not actually update any software but instead the index of the repository so it is fine to use. Now given an updated repository I can get the software I need easily. This is as opposed to apt-get upgrade in which it will update (or "upgrade") the packages to the newest versions and thus ruining the customization of the system.